# Platform UNO Navigation extension documentation

Tags: uno-platform

The navigation in my current UWP code base is based on MvvmCross and ViewModel to ViewModel navigation. According to the UnoConf21 this should be possible with the new Navigation extension. I used the following code for registering a list page from which I want to navigate to a detail page:

```
.Register(ViewMap.For(nameof(ListAPage)).Show<ListAPage>().With<ListAPageViewModel>())
.Register(ViewMap.For(nameof(DetailAPage)).Show<DetailAPage>().With<DetailAPageViewModel>())
```

In the list page viewmodel I call

```
navigator.NavigateViewModelForResultAsync<DetailAPageViewModel, SomeDataType>(sender:this, data:someData);
```

I get to the detail page, but unfortunately I don't see a way of getting the parameter data out of that request. Going back from the detail page I want to pass some data back:

```
navigator.NavigatePreviousWithResultAsync<SomeDataType>(sender:this, data: someUpdatedData);
```

The original list page viewmodel gets the updated data. But the view unfortunately created also a new viewmodel so the updated data is lost.

Does anyone know how to use the navigation extension? Or is there a good sample or documentation about the API?

Thanks, Ronald

Answer (score 0):

We've got more samples and documentation in the works. In the meantime, you should be able to prevent the view from being recreated (and thus the viewmodel) by setting the NavigationCacheMode property on the page to Required.

Nick

Comment: The NavigationCacheMode=Required works ok to get updated back when going back to the intitial page (ListAPage). But I still haven't figured out how to get data from the intitial page (ListAPage) to the next page (DetailAPage). Any suggestions? Looking forward to the samples and documentation!